# Equation with 3 unknowns

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> For which values of $a$ and $b$ does the function $f(x)=\sqrt{ax+b}$ satisfy the equation $f'(x)=2f(x)-\frac{4x}{f(x)}$?

This is what I have done so far: $y=\sqrt{ax+b}, \ y'= \frac{a}{2\sqrt{ax+b}}
$
And therefore:$\frac{a}{2\sqrt{ax+b}}=2\sqrt{ax+b}-\frac{4x}{\sqrt{ax+b}} $

But I can't solve this equation. I thought about substituting $ 
u=\sqrt{ax+b}$, but I get stuck there too.

I do know the answers are: $a=2$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Multiplying by $2\sqrt{ax+b}$, $a=4(ax+b)-8x=(4a-8)x+4b$.

Comment: How do I get from there to $a=2$ and $b=1/2$?

Comment: @tomcajot Like YvesDaoust pointed out $a=(4a-8)x+4b$. The LHS is a constant, so the RHS is constant only if $4a-8=0$. Now you can easily solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Three unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from
$\frac{a}{2\sqrt{ax+b}}=2\sqrt{ax+b}-\frac{4x}{\sqrt{ax+b}}$

We have:

$4(a-2)x-a+4b=0$

In order for this equation to be identically null for any value of x, it must occur that:

$a-2=0$

$-a+4b=0$

at the same time.

This is true for the values of $a=2$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks, that's it!